# ViewController controls not visible, but present in document guideline

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am newbie in Xamarin iOS development.

I created a storyboard, added few view controllers in it.
I added some controls in one view controller, ran the code and checked the output on simulator. All worked great.
Now after some time I checked my storyboard design. Now the controls are not visible in view controller(in story board), but they are visible in document guideline(view hierarchy).

please let me know what should I do to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working in Xamarin Studio? I've noticed a lot of bugs in Xamarin Studio regarding storyboards. Tried opening the storyboard in Xcode?

Comment: I am working with visual studio 2017 in MAC

Comment: Do you set constraints to the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by clicking on the Portrait/Landscape icon two times which changed the device width to "Compact" and height to "Regular" an in 5 seconds the controls were visible in the `ViewController`